# Cordova Run a JavaScript Function in Background

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

I know that there have been many questions asked on this there have been plugins written etc. But I still haven't managed to find a way out. The most talked out and the best plugin for this is [here](https://github.com/Red-Folder/Cordova-Plugin-BackgroundService).

But what I fail to achieve is in the background I want to run MyService, subscribe to the ONLINE event which tells me that internet connection is available. And when it is execute a javascript function.

It would be great if guys could help me with this as I am a newbie when it comes to all this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this problem? If so, you could share?

Answer (score -1):

try with javascripts `setInterval()` and call any function from this...it will work as a service.
for more information try 
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_setinterval